# Crear archivos con nombre que incluyen caracteres raros

Tags: php, python

He estado buscando demasiado pero no he encontrado la respuesta, el caso es el siguiente:

1. Con PHP tengo que obtener el listado de los archivos de un
   directorio.
2. El listado lo tengo que guardar en un archivo con formato JSON, para lo cual utilizo `json_encode()`.
3. El archivo guardado lo descargo desde un cliente con Python 2.7.3
4. Se debe de leer el archivo y crear archivos a partir de los nombres
   guardados en el archivo.

A continuación el código de como lo realizo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

function listar_directorios_ruta($repository) {
    $response = array();
    try
    {
       if (is_dir($repository))
       {
          $files = new FilesystemIterator($repository);

          foreach ($files as $file) {
             if ($file->getFilename()[0] === '.') continue;

             array_push($response, array(
                'name' => $file->getFilename()
             ));
          }
       }
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
    }

   return $response;
}

$response['files'] = listar_directorios_ruta('directorio');

$responseJSON = json_encode($response);

file_put_contents('listado_archivos.json', $responseJSON);
```

En el directorio tengo un solo archivo llamado ñ.txt, al crear el archivo si aparece ñ.txt, hasta aquí "todo bien".

Hago lo siguiente en Python (en linea de comando):

```
>>>test = open('listado_archivos.json').read()
>>>test
'n\xcc\x83.txt'
>>>
>>>print test
ñ.txt
>>>
>>>newFile = open(test, 'w')
>>>createFile.write('Contenido para el archivo')
>>>createFile.close()
```

Trato de mostrar el contenido del archivo:

```
# cat ñ.txt
cat: can't open 'ñ.txt': No such file or directory
```

Pero si hago lo siguiente directo con Python, si funciona:

```
>>> test = 'ñ.txt'
>>> test
'\xc3\xb1.txt'
>>>
>>> print test
ñ.txt
>>>
>>> newFile = open(test, 'w')
>>> newFile.write('Contenido para el archivo')
>>> newFile.close()
>>> quit()

# cat ñ.txt
Contenido para el archivo
```

La codificación de la ñ cuando viene desde PHP es distinta a la de Python.

Como hacer para que PHP convierta o interprete de forma correcta la ñ para que Python pueda crear el archivo de forma correcta?

Saludos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está pasando aparentemente es que ambos lenguajes están trabajando con Unicode (UTF-8 en concreto) pero usando caracteres diferentes pero canónicamente equivalentes.

En Unicode se conoce como carácter compuesto a una entidad (code-point) Unicode que puede definirse como una secuencia de otros caracteres. (`ó = 0 + '`, `ñ = n + ~`, `à = a +`, etc)

PHP está enviando  la `ñ` como una secuencia `U+006E` + `U+0303` (`n` + `~`). Por otro lado Python usa el code-point  `U+00F1` (`ñ`), que es un carácter compuesto.

**Son considerados *canónicamente equivalentes* pero no iguales**, tienen el mismo aspecto y significado cuando se imprimen pero se forman con diferentes code-points.

Desde el lado de Python, lo que puedes hacer es normalizar la cadena UTF-8 codificada que recibes para obtener su forma compuesta. Para ello podemos usar [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) de la biblioteca estándar:

```
>>> test = 'n\xcc\x83.txt'
>>> test = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', test.decode("UTF-8")).encode("UTF-8")
>>> test
'\xc3\xb1.txt'
```

En PHP puedes usar [Normalizer::normalize](http://php.net/manual/es/class.normalizer.php).

Comment: Realicé las pruebas con la respuesta que me proporcionaste, las cuales fueron exitosas.

Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Saludos...